# Warning while using RDD in for comprehension

Tags: scala, apache-spark, for-comprehension, rdd

I get a warning when using an RDD in a for comprension, and I'm not sure if it's something I'm doing wrong.  If I do this:

```
val sc = new SparkContext(...)

val anRDD = sc.parallelize(List(
  ("a", List(1, 2, 3)), 
  ("b", List(4), 
  ("c", List(5, 6))
)

for {
  (someString, listOfInts) <- anRDD
  someInt <- listOfInts
} yield (someString, someInt)
```

Then I get this output:

```
 warning: `withFilter' method does not yet exist on org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, List[Int])], using `filter' method instead
  (s, li) <- rl
```

But it does still successfully return a FlatMappedRDD[(String, Int)].  Am I doing something wrong?  Or is it safe to ignore this warning?

**Update:** I would also accept as an answer how the for-comprehension converts these operations to map/flatMap/filter calls, since I didn't think there'd be any filter or withFilter calls required.  I assumed it would be equivalent to something similar to this:

```
anRDD.flatMap(tuple => tuple.map(someInt => (tuple._1, someInt)))
```

But this doesn't include any filter or withFilter calls, which seems to be the source of the warning.

Oh, I'm using Spark 1.2.0, Scala 2.10.4, and this is all within the REPL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I am no expert, but have done some digging and here is what I have found:

I compiled the code using `-print` (since JavaDecompiler was failing for some reason), which will print out the program with all Scala-specific features removed. There, I saw:

```
test.this.anRDD().filter({
    (new anonymous class anonfun$1(): Function1)
  }).flatMap({
    (new anonymous class anonfun$2(): Function1)
  }, ClassTag.apply(classOf[scala.Tuple2]));
```

You will notice the `filter`...so, I checked on the `anonfun$1`:

```
public final boolean apply(Tuple2<String, List<Object>> check$ifrefutable$1)
  {
    Tuple2 localTuple2 = check$ifrefutable$1;
    boolean bool;
    if (localTuple2 != null) {
      bool = true;
    } else {
      bool = false;
    }
    return bool;
  }
```

So, if you put all of this together, it seems that the `filter` is happening in the comprehension because it is filtering out anything that is NOT a `Tuple2`.

And, the preference is to use `withFilter` instead of `filter` (not sure why atm). You can see that by decompiling a regular list instead of an `RDD`

```
object test {
  val regList = List(
  ("a", List(1, 2, 3)), 
  ("b", List(4)),
  ("c", List(5, 6))
  )

val foo = for {
  (someString, listOfInts) <- regList
  someInt <- listOfInts
} yield (someString, someInt)
}
```

Which decompiles to:

```
test.this.regList().withFilter({
  (new anonymous class anonfun$1(): Function1)
}).flatMap({
  (new anonymous class anonfun$2(): Function1)
}, immutable.this.List.canBuildFrom()).$asInstanceOf[List]();
```

So, it is the same thing, except it uses `withFilter` where it can

Comment: Not necessarily.  Where does the withFilter call come in?  I'm assuming (as I always do with Scala) that it's due to an implicit conversion somewhere, but I don't see why it matters here, since the for-comprehension shows it's calling .filter, not .withFilter

Comment: Because the preference is to use withFilter per the warning. It just falls back to the filter method in this case.

Comment: @jayhutfles I just added more, showing the preference for withFilter

Comment: Yep, I wasn't familiar with the difference between filter and withFilter until now.  The RDD class doesn't provide withFilter, which I thought was a probelm.  But RDD's are lazy by definition, so there isn't really a need for the efficiency normally provided in withFilter.

Thanks, this was really helpful.  Didn't know about the -print option either...

Answer (score -2):

Call collect() in the RDD before sending it to the comprehension.

```
val collectedList = anRDD.collect
for {
  (someString, listOfInts) <- collectedList
  someInt <- listOfInts
} yield (someString, someInt)
```